# Income Tax Question on participating in a funeral service

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I participated in a funeral service and was given a $100 check for doing so. Is that considered income (i.e. Other Income) on federal income taxes or is it treated as a gift?

---

The check was written from the business. The funeral home says they do not produce a 1099.

Comment: Was this from the family, or, the Funeral Parlor business ?

Answer (score 6):

You were paid $100 by a US business. Therefore you should report it on your tax return. If this was in 2020, then report it on the tax return to be submitted in April 2021; if you received the money in 2021 then it will be on the form you submit in April 2022.

The company will not generally send you a 1099 if the total compensation is less than $600.

Note: if your total income from all sources is small enough you might not have to file a return.

Comment: +1.  If you do not have a "business" that you are running, and this is essentially a one-time gig, it goes on Schedule 1, Line 8 "Other Income."  See [this question for more information](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/121992/10997).